# Comparing mean of subgroup with national mean

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

I am analyzing a dataset. Each row corresponds to a participant who answered a questionnaire. Each participant is assigned a score based on their answers. I calculated the average score for each regional subgroup and I am interested in a statistical test that would suggest whether some regional subgroup's average score differs significantly from the national average. I am interested in a test whose assumptions regarding the distributions are minimal (for instance, I am not inclined to assume that the distributions are normal).
Any suggestions?

By the way, I am working on R.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the individual scores available to you? If so, and if you don't want to make any assumption about the distribution, you can use a non-parametric test: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239293/non-parametric-altervative-to-one-sample-t-test

Comment: Wouldn't  a test taking into account the distribution of the population mean be better? I should have actually used the term "sample" instead of "population" as we are estimating the population mean based on the sample

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. You are then interested in a 2 sample test, regional sub-group vs the rest, correct?If that is the case, you can use a permutation test

Comment: Well, not exactly. It's regional subgroup + entire sample (i.e. regional subgroup + rest of sample)

Comment: Then you are still ok to use permutation test because regardless of the permutation, you will still have the same population mean.

Comment: It's not the population mean though, it's only the sample mean. So it seems intuitive to me that the test should take into account the distribution around the sample mean, no?