# Wilcoxon signed rank test for likert data and composite scores

Tags: r, nonparametric, survey, likert, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a survey where I used seven point Likert scale for all the questions. With 1 being Completely disagree to 7 meaning Completely agree.

I wanted to combine multiple questions (let's say 7 of them) into a single composite score which I did using factor analysis to derive single factor scores, which was then rescaled to 1 to 7 scale.

Now, since the data is skewed, I wanted to use one sample Wilcoxon signed rank test with median 4 to test if this variable is greater than the median 4. This would let me infer whether the respondents generally support the thing in question or not and report the pseudomedian like this (HL=2.85 95% CI [2.75, 2.95], p<0.001).

Is there something wrong with this approach?

Further should I be using one sample Wilcoxon signed rank test for reporting the answers to single questions? I don't see it used very often like this, why is that?

Comment: I think this one answers your question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239293/non-parametric-altervative-to-one-sample-t-test

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Based on this, I don't think my approach is wrong. I tried to follow every rule/assumption, but I don't know what I don't know. I am afraid that my approach was nonstandard in some way (i.e. I don't see it used that much).